# how to get all of string values from dictionary and object in C#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, object, dictionary

How can I get all the `string` values from this `Dictionary`

```
class MyObject
{
public string MyString { get; set; }
public int MyInteger { get; set; }
}
    Dictionary<int, MyObject> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();
```

How can I get all `Mystring` into a `string[]` ? 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
string[] result = dictionary.Values.Select(x=> x.MyString).ToArray();
```

A Dictionary object has 2 Properties : `Keys` and `Values` . You can make use of them when you want.

- `Values` contains a Collection of all the Values inside the dictionary.
- `Select` is used as a projection to get only the `MyString` property in `MyObject`.
- `ToArray` extension method converts the result into an array as the expected result in your question.

Comment: Thnaks for answer , Its dont work . Its get object but i want somthing like dictionary.values.mystring

Comment: @hadi.k This answer does exactly what you want.

Comment: `Dictionary.Values` is a list of all the `MyObject` in your dictionary. `.Select(x => x.MyString)` grabs only the item you're looking for, and `.ToArray()` turns it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] allStrings = dictionary.Values.ToArray();
```